# Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$cart (Codeigniter 3)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi guys I'm using codeigniter 3 for a project. Now I need to add a cart system to it. So I'm trying to use CI's default Cart Class for it.
But when I try to load it through view it gives me an error message

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$cart

This is my Cart.php which is the controller.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cart extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct (){
        
        parent::__construct();

        
        $this->load->helper(array('url','language','form'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('cart');
        $this->load->view('home/cart');
    }

    public function update(){
        
        $this->load->library('cart');
        $this->cart->update($_POST);
        redirect(base_url().'home/cart');
    }

    public function add_variables(){
        
        $this->load->library('cart');
        $data = array(
            array(
                       'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
                       'qty'     => 1,
                       'price'   => 39.95,
                       'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
                       'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
                    ),
               array(
                       'id'      => 'sku_567ZYX',
                       'qty'     => 1,
                       'price'   => 9.95,
                       'name'    => 'Coffee Mug'
                    ),
               array(
                       'id'      => 'sku_965QRS',
                       'qty'     => 1,
                       'price'   => 29.95,
                       'name'    => 'Shot Glass'
                    )
        );

        $this->cart->insert($data); 
    }
}
```

and This is my view (cart.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cart<title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php $this->load->view('home/top-bar'); ?>
    <div id="page">
        <?php $this->load->view('home/header'); ?>

        <div id="center-right">
            <h1>This is Cart</h1>
        <?php echo form_open(base_url().'Cart/update'); ?>

<table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%" border="0">

<tr>
  <th>QTY</th>
  <th>Item Description</th>
  <th style="text-align:right">Item Price</th>
  <th style="text-align:right">Sub-Total</th>
</tr>

<?php $i = 1; ?>

<?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>

        <?php echo form_hidden($i.'[rowid]', $items['rowid']); ?>

        <tr>
          <td><?php echo form_input(array('name' => $i.'[qty]', 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5')); ?></td>
          <td>
                <?php echo $items['name']; ?>

                        <?php if ($this->cart->has_options($items['rowid']) == TRUE): ?>

                                <p>
                                        <?php foreach ($this->cart->product_options($items['rowid']) as $option_name => $option_value): ?>

                                                <strong><?php echo $option_name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $option_value; ?><br />

                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </p>

                        <?php endif; ?>

          </td>
          <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['price']); ?></td>
          <td style="text-align:right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['subtotal']); ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php $i++; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2"> </td>
  <td class="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
  <td class="right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total()); ?></td>
</tr>

</table>

<p><?php echo form_submit('', 'Update your Cart'); ?></p>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <?php $this->load->view('home/footer'); ?>    

</body>
</html>
```

Could someone give me a help on this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your controller class name cart to other name because cart class already used that name try to change

Comment: OMG.. I was doing this for two days.. searched everywhere.. but couldn't find the answer..
That works mate.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session','cart');

my problem is solve by adding cart in autoload.php file